# Ubuntu unable to detect external USB hard drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

I tried mounting external usb hard drive.But it does'nt detect.

Here is `dmesg` log:

```
[ 3025.963395] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, address 3
[ 3194.935661] usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[ 3195.042576] scsi7 : uas
[ 3215.680689] scsi 7:0:0:0: uas_eh_abort_handler tag -1
[ 3215.680708] scsi 7:0:0:0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler tag -1
[ 3215.680721] scsi 7:0:0:0: uas_eh_target_reset_handler tag -1
[ 3215.680727] scsi 7:0:0:0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler tag -1
[ 3215.684900] usb 2-1.2: URB BAD STATUS -71
[  3215.752727] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[ 3215.845484] scsi 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

Can you please help me?